# 15.04 GUI icons (Buttons) not responding to mouse over

Tags: mouse, icons, gui, system, system-tray

I've recently installed updates and they broke my GUI... :(

problem is that I don't know what did it..

Here is what is happening:
When I mouse over an icon in the tray, it doesn't light up like it used to...

any ideas?